# magento 2 extension composer update error - Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, extensions, composer, uninstall-module

My Siteground shared hosting plan does not allow me to use composer (memory limit). How can I fix this issue? is there a way to manually update it without composer? or how can I disable this module? Thanks!

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory. The following modules are outdated: Magefan_Community db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.2, currently installed - 2.0.3 Magefan_Community db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.2, currently installed - 2.0.3
```

========================================================================

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 844111872) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule.php on line 76
```

Comment: what is command that you want to run ?

Comment: trying to run "composer install" and received the above |Fatal error: Out of memory  ...." thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Did you ever manage to resolve this? I am having the same issue. We recently signed up to Siteground and are trying to upgrade our website from Magento 2.2.5 to Magento 2.3.

When trying to run Composer Update I have the exact same problem.

I tried running commands such as 'php -d memory_limit=512M /usr/local/bin/composer update' but no luck what so ever.

Any help with this would be so much appreciated!
```

I had to cloned the magento site to the local computer and run it using xampp, and run those composer commands and upload the changes back to siteground.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

php -d memory_limit=512M /usr/local/bin/composer update

Let me know if not solved!

Comment: It required me to run "composer update" before "composer Install" and it's having the same memory error:

Comment: mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 839917568) (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 77

Comment: You are still setting a maximum amount of memory php can use and the command you run still needs more. Not an ideal solution but the easiest way is to use php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update || install. Using -1 tells php to use no memory limit so it will run until complete or the operating system runs out of memory and kills process. This was is better than guessing about how much maximum memory to allocate.

Comment: Hi, i also tried using the -1, but the hosting provider is limit it to 768M maximum for php memory limit. Is there any other way to get around it?